Linearity of expected value and what it implies
In some problem I was doing, it involves a trial where given some value $x$, $50\%$ of the time it will go to $0$ at the next step, and $50\%$ of the time it will go to $2x$. Notation-wise, is it fine to write such a process as $E(X=x)=0.5\cdot0+0.5\cdot E(X=2x)=0.5\cdot E(X=2x)$, where $X$ is some random variable?
And if I then have some function $f$ that satisfies $f(x)=E(X=x)$, can I say that $f(x)=ax$ for some constant $a$, given the linearity of expected value? Or am I misunderstanding the idea of linearity in the context of expected value?
I know this is a lot of questions but I have a feeling that I'm representing my ideas with inaccurate notations (I'm not sure if $E(X=x)$ is a thing because I usually see it as just $E(X)$) and would like some suggestions on how I can write my ideas more accurately. I can also share the original problem if more context is needed.

Linearity of expectation just has to do with this: if $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables, then
$$
E(X + Y) = E(X) + E(Y)
$$
and if $c$ is some constant, then
$$
E(cX) = cE(X)
$$
As for your problem, I think sharing the entire exercise would be helpful.

@PaulAsh yes I know that already but that still doesn't answer my question as to whether or not it can be translated to $f(x)=ax$. I tried to read the Wikipedia page on linear maps but it was a bit complicated to understand, but it did give one of the examples as $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R:x\mapsto cx$ so I was wondering if that could be applied here.

What you have might more properly be called a stochastic process, essentially a sequence of random numbers that may have some relationship between them. In your case, you have a starting value $X_0$, then $X_1$ is a random variable which with probability 50% is equal to 0, and with probability 50% is equal to $2X_0$. Similarly, $X_2$ is another random variable which is equal to $0$ or $2X_1$ with probability 50% each.
At each step $n$ you have a corresponding value $X_n$ which is the result of applying this process $n$ times. Because the value of $X_n$ is determined only by the value of $X_{n-1}$ and random chance, your process is actually a special kind of stochastic process called a Markov chain. You would refer to the entire chain using the notation $X = (X_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ or just $(X_n)_n$, a sequence of random variables indexed by $n$.
Now, given a large but fixed $n$, you can study what possible values the variable $X_n$ can take. A first natural question is: for a given value $x$, what is the probability that $X_n = x$? This would be denoted $P(X_n = x)$, where $[X_n = x]$ is a bit of notation denoting "the event in which $X_n$ is equal to $x$". Events have probabilities, and $P([X_n = x])$ denotes that probability, though we typically suppress the square brackets $[\ ]$ because it looks better.
A second natural question is: what is the typical or average value of $X_n$? This is called the expected value or expectation of $X_n$ and is denoted $E(X_n)$. When people say "expectation is linear", they mean that the expected value operator $E$ distributes over sums and scalars. That is, if you considered another random variable like $Y = 2X_n$ or $Z = X_n + Y$, then it would hold that $E(Y) = 2 E(X_n)$ and $E(Z) = E(X_n) + E(Y)$. In other words: given two random variables $X$ and $Y$ and scalars $a,b$, it holds that $E(aX + bY) = aE(X) + bE(Y)$.

[Edit] Here are some further thoughts on your problem: If your starting value is $X_0 = x_0$, then $X_1$ takes the values $2x_0$ and $0$ with probability $50\%$ each. Thus in $25\%$ of cases it holds that $X_2 = 4x_0$ and in $75\%$ of cases it holds that $X_2 = 0$. In general, $X_n$ has a $1/2^n$ probability of having the value $2^nx_0$, otherwise the value will be $0$. Consequently, the expected value is $E(X_n) = (1/2^n)(2^n x_0) + 0 = x_0$, the same as the starting value $X_0$.

This is a lot of new stuff but I'm not sure how to use such ideas into my problem. Thanks for the info regardless.

Also could you elaborate on if a translation to $f(x)=ax$ is applicable? I tried to read the Wikipedia page on linear maps but it was quite complicated. Though I did see one of the examples it gives is $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R:x\mapsto cx$ so I was wondering if that was applicable here.

Translations, like $f(x) = x + 1$, are not linear maps because $2(x+1)$ is not the same as $(2x) + 1$, but they do fit into the wider class of affine maps, which are maps of the form $f(x) = ax + b$. But in the case of expectations of random variables, if $X$ is a random variable then it does in fact hold that $E(2X+1) = 2E(X) + 1$, but this is because $1$ as a constant function can be thought of as a "random" variable whose value is always $1$, and therefore has expected value $E(1) = 1$.

I mean a translation from $f(x)=E(X=x)$ to $f(x)=ax$.

"I mean a translation from $f(x) = E(X = x)$ to $f(x) = ax$"; that's not really a translation, that's just calculating what the expected value of your situation is.  (Assuming you mean $X$ to be the next step in your trial, the expected value of that next step is just $x$ by direct calculation, and as shown above in the answer even for later steps it's still true.) We didn't use the linearity of expected value to get there, even though the answer is a thing that is linear in $x$.

@Rob, not to be judgemental, but I think your notation could be a tad misleading since what you have found is, in fact, an expectation of a single step $i \in [1; n]$, whereas the author presumably is seeking for the expectation of the displacement — which is the sum of those steps. I would be grateful if you were to add the sum and showcase the linearity of the expectation in computing the displacement.
